# With an external 4k monitor, how do I set the highest resolution AND increase font size?

Tags: macos, 4k-resolution

I recently got a new Dell S2721QS 27" 4K monitor. I don't use my MacBook Pro's screen; I use this Dell monitor as my primary display.

I want to use the highest resolution to get a lot of space to do work, but it becomes really hard to read:

[image]

How can I get the full resolution and increase the font size so I don't have to squint my eyes?

Comment: It's an either/or. Can't have cake & eat it. Best you can do is increase the web page sizing, Cmd/+ will do that. Interface size is dependant on the Display pref. Personally., I'd have gone for 2 x 27" 2k monitors for the screen real estate. I consider "HiDPI/retina' screens to be little more than marketing hype. I've a 55" 4k, fine as a TV, lousy as a monitor, as you have to sit 18" from it to read it.

Comment: I've never used it myself but I understand SwitchResX is monitor control *way* more than Apple's minimal control panel. It might do the trick and there is a free 10 day trial... https://www.madrau.com